# Async validation with Ko.validation and Ko.mapping

Tags: asynchronous, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-validation

Im using ko.validation and ko.mapping to display some data in a table. This data can be editted or more data can be added to the table.

see fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/juandozco/v9L69g8a/5/

Im reusing the form to edit or create this items. My problem is, some of the properties in the items cant be editted, so im hidding those properties in the edit mode, but the validation still happens and doesnt let the form continue.

I tried 3 different things, see lines:

> 1, 90 and 112 in the javascript section in my fiddle

how can i achieve this validation?

Comment: if you are hiding and no need of edit on `Username` why you are extending it in first place . please clarify

Comment: Im extending it because im using the same form to edit and insert. I need to validate it when im inserting a new item.

Comment: this should work `self.User().userName.extend({ validatable: false });` keep it at start of `self.edit` function inside

Comment: It works, kinda. It seems to be turning off that validations and all others with it. it doesnt work back if i set it back to true

Comment: can you give me a sample explaining your issue . as far i see for edit part it working well .

Comment: See the fiddle in your answer, if you do that, yes it stops the validation in the edit mode. But when you save and go back to insert or edit another item, there are no more error messages, for example in the email validation.

Comment: i believe there is issue with `insertMessages:true` we can choose a different way to deal this check here via `validationMessage` check here http://fiddle.jshell.net/v9L69g8a/8/

Comment: Oh, youre totally right. Yes, this did the thing. Thank you a lot. And thank you for your fast and patient answers.

Comment: glad i could help . cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you need to `skip` the validation on edit part so you need do add extender like `validatable: false` on your observable .

**Code :**

```
self.edit = function (user) {
    self.User().userName.extend({ validatable: false }); // Key here
    self.editing(true);
    ............
    self.User().userName(user.userName());
};
```

working sample **[here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/v9L69g8a/7/)**

Comment: We also set the `insertMessages` in the `ko.validation.init` options to `false` and added custom `<span>` with the `data-bind` set to `validationMessage` to each of the validations to show the validation messages.